# What does "2<&1" redirect do in Bourne shell?

Tags: bash, shell, redirect, sh

`2>&1` redirect in Bourne shell takes the output sent to a file descriptor 2 (by default, standard error) and sends it instead to file descriptor 1 (by default a standard output).

But what does `2<&1` redirect do?

Does it send stderr to stdin?

My theory was that it was sending stdin to stderr (e.g. same as `1>&2`) but experimentally, that is NOT the case:

```
$ perl -e 'print "OUT\n"; print STDERR "ERR\n"; \
  while (<>) { print "IN WAS $_\n";}'           \
  > out3 2<&1
df
$ cat out3
ERR
OUT
IN WAS df
```

Note that standard out AND standard error both went to file out3 where stdout was redirected.

Comment: As a note - this was a (supposed) bug a co-worker put in when he mistakingly used `<` instead of `>`. I'm just tryng to undderstand exactly what Shell is doing with it. So far, it SEEMS as if it's the same as `2>&1`

Comment: @user112358132134 - `GNU bash, version 2.03.0(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.5.1)`

Comment: The traditional technique for handling the terminal was to do `close(0); fd = open(`/dev/tty`, O_RDWR);` (which would always return `fd == 0` since that was the lowest file descriptor not in use), followed by: `close(1); dup(0); close(2); dup(2);` so that all three of standard input, standard output and standard error, at the file descriptor level, were readable and writable. Tricks (typos?) such as `2<&1` therefore 'worked', but somewhat by accident, usually; seldom did people really work out what they intended. Officially, `2<&1` means 'set stderr so it reads from the same file as stdout'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<&` operator duplicates an “input” file descriptor.  According to IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 (aka Single Unix Specification v3, the successor to POSIX), it's supposed to be an error to say `2<&1` if 1 is not a file descriptor open for input.  However, it appears that `bash` is lazy and doesn't care if the file descriptor is open for input or for output.

So both `2<&1` and `2>&1` simply perform the system call `dup2(1, 2)`, which copies file descriptor 1 to file descriptor 2.

You can check by running a command like this, since redirections are performed left-to-right:

```
sleep 99999 1>/dev/null 2<&1
```

Then in another window, run `lsof` on the `sleep` process.  You'll see that both file descriptors 1 and 2 point to `/dev/null`.  Example (on my Mac):

```
:; ps axww | grep sleep
 8871 s001  R+     0:00.01 grep sleep
 8869 s003  S+     0:00.01 sleep 99999
:; lsof -p 8869 | tail -2
sleep   8869 mayoff    1w   CHR    3,2       0t0       316 /dev/null
sleep   8869 mayoff    2w   CHR    3,2       0t0       316 /dev/null
```

Comment: So, you're saying `2<&1` is **effectively** equivalent to `2>&1` in Bash (especially for command that doesn't read from STDIN), even if theoretically it shouldn't be, correct?

Comment: Not quite.  `2<&1` is equivalent to `1>&2`.

Comment: sorry, that doesn't seem to jibe with my test (see the question). ERR was redirected to OUT, seemingly, not vice versa

Comment: It exactly matches the test in your question.  You redirected fd 1 to `out3`, then by saying `2<&1` you copied fd 1 to fd 2.

Comment: shouldn't copying 1 tp 2 then redirect 1 from out3 to wherever err went?

Comment: You're right, my claim that `2<&1` is equivalent to `1>&2` was incorrect.

Comment: Both `x<&y` and `x>&y` perform the system call `dup2(y, x)`.

Comment: can you please edit the results of the discussion esp. details from last comment into the answer so I can accept? Thx

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the parser code in the source for Bash, it seems that `2>&1` is treated in the same way as `2<&1`.

**parse.y**

```
|   NUMBER LESS_AND NUMBER
        {
          redir.dest = $3;
          $$ = make_redirection ($1, r_duplicating_input, redir);
        }
...
|   NUMBER GREATER_AND NUMBER
        {
          redir.dest = $3;
          $$ = make_redirection ($1, r_duplicating_output, redir);
        }
```

Looking through the redirection source `redir.c`, the constants `r_duplicating_input` and `r_duplicating_output` seem to be treated in the same way.  Same as in the `make_redirection` function in `make_cmd.c`.

Testing with a simple program that prints "yay" to stdout and "nay" to stderr, I can confirm your test results:

```
$ ./a.out > out 2>&1
$ cat out
nay
yay
$ ./a.out > out 2<&1
$ cat out
nay
yay
$ ./a.out > out 1>&2
yay
nay
$ cat out
$ ./a.out > out 1<&2
yay
nay
$ cat out
$
```

Answer (score 0):

From `man bash` under *REDIRECTION*:

```
   Duplicating File Descriptors
       The redirection operator

              [n]<&word

       is used to duplicate input  file  descriptors.   If  word
       expands  to  one  or  more  digits,  the  file descriptor
       denoted by n is made to be a copy of that  file  descrip‐
       tor.   If  the  digits  in  word  do  not  specify a file
       descriptor open for input, a  redirection  error  occurs.
       If  word evaluates to -, file descriptor n is closed.  If
       n is not specified, the standard input  (file  descriptor
       0) is used.
```

So in the case of *2<&1*, it seems that `2` (*stderr*) is made to be a copy of `1` (*stdout*). I've tested it with the other way around `1<&2` makes *stdout* to be a copy of *stderr*.

So in a test program:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo hello 1<&2
```

When run on command line, *hello* is output to *stderr* not *stdout*

```
$ ./test > /dev/null
hello
$ ./test > /dev/null 2>&1
$
```

Comment: Your test tested the wrong redirect. I know what 2>&1 does - please read the question carefully

Comment: The test in my answer was for 1<&2 in the test program, the 2>&1 was just making sure that 1<&2 did in fact duplicate stderr