# Understand Redirection with >&

Tags: unix

I know 0 , 1, 2 are STDIN , STDOUT and STDERR file descriptors. 
I am trying to understand redirection. 
'>' means dump to a file
'>>' means append

But what does '>&' do ?
Also what is the step by step process for the following commands ?

```
command > file 2>&1       
command > file 2<&1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NUMBER1>&NUMBER2` means to assign the file descriptor NUMBER2 the file descriptor NUMBER1.

That means, to execute `dup2 (NUMBER2, NUMBER1)`.

```
command > file 2>&1
```

Bash process the command line, it finds first the redirection `>file`, it changes stdout to be written to `file`, then continue to process and finds `2>&1`, and changes stderr to  be written to stdout (which is `file` in this moment) .

```
command > file 2<&1
```

this is the same, but `2<&1` redirects stderr to `read` from stdout. Because nobody reads from stderr, this second redirection **normally** has no effect.

However, bash treats this special case doing the same as for `2>&1`, so executing `dup2 (1, 2)`.

[What does "2<&1" redirect do in Bourne shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334315/what-does-21-redirect-do-in-bourne-shell)

Comment: The last sentence is incorrect.  `2>&1` is exactly identical to `2<&1`.  The choice of `<` or `>` when dup'ing a file descriptor is irrelevant, and both redirections have exactly the same result.

Answer (score 5):

Let's analyze it step by step:

- `>place` means reopen the standard output so that it begins writing to `place`, which is a file name that will be open for writing. This is the typical redirection.
- `N>place` does the same for an arbitrary file descriptor *n*. For example, `2>place` redirects the standard error, file descriptor 2, to `place`. `1>place` is the same as `>place`.
- If *place* is written with the special syntax `&N`, it will be treated as an existing file descriptor number rather than a file name. So, `>&2` and `1>&2` both mean reopen the standard output to write to standard error, and `2>&1` is the other way around.

The exact same goes for input, except *place* and the descriptors are opened for reading, and the file descriptor left of the `<` sign defaults to 0, which stands for standard input. `2<&1` means "reopen file descriptor 2 for reading so that future reads from it actually read from file descriptor 1". This doesn't make sense in a normal program since both file descriptors 1 and 2 are open for writing.

Comment: one more question, what if I give `command >& log` , here `place` is in the special syntax `&log` , but its a string and not 0/1/2 , so will  `log` be considered a file if its not 0/1/2 ?

Comment: @hack3r In this case it's `>&` that is special, and `log` is just a file. `>& file` is a shorthand for `>file 2>&1` that some shells implement—it redirects both stdout and stderr to `file`.

Answer (score 1):

`2>&1` means redirect `STDERR` to the same place that `STDOUT` is going to. One example where it's useful is `grep` which normally works on `STDOUT` this makes it work on `STDOUT` and `STDERR`:

```
app 2>&1 | grep hello
```